# Making liquorice--temperature advice

Tags: temperature, candy

We're experimenting with making black liquorice from scratch. We've been using backstrap molasses, liquorice root powder, aniseed powder, and star anise. All the recipes we've found say equal part molasses to equal part flour, to thicken. The flavour has been great, as well as consistency, but we can't seem to get it as hard as we'd like. We're going for the thickness of a Finnish Panda liquorice, not a very chewy or hard. None of the recipes we've found seem to stress a temp. Has anyone tried this and have a temp they can advise? Get the sugar to 130C before adding flour, for example?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

[These folks](https://www.chefsteps.com/activities/licorice) add sugar mixture to heated gelatin, then bring to a boil before adding flour. Then cook again with flour. They vary the texture with the flour addition.  More flour creates a firmer product.